# How can I convert this field from string to Double

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana

I need to convert this field in my Elasticsearch cluster from string to double manually. I want to keep the field as a string and I can't inject any new fields. My code is getting this error: `[Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [sum].]`. I'm testing my query out in dev_tools in Kibana. Can anybody help here?

```
GET /csv_metrics_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "object_key": "example.csv"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "event_path":  "path/to/example.csv"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
          "sum": {
          "script": "Double.parseDouble(doc['stat_value'].value)"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add aggs

```
GET /csv_metrics_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "object_key": "example.csv"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "event_path":  "path/to/example.csv"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
          "statCount": {
          "sum": {
          "script": "Double.parseDouble(doc['stat_value'].value)"
          }
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: I get this error: `"reason" : "wrong_method_type_exception: cannot convert MethodHandle(Longs)long to (Object)String"`

Comment: please add stat_value mapping to your question